# Wenn es um Kartenspielen geht, was bedeutet „Gustierzeichen“?

Tags: translation

In „Meister Preference“, ein Heft von der Wiener Spielkartenfabrik Ferdinand Piatnik & Söhne, copyright 1971, steht:

> Für Preference werden eigene Karten verwendet, nämlich französische Karten **ohne** Gustierzeichen.

Dann steht:

> Bei Preference stehen die vier Farben in einer bestimmten Reihenfolge, un zwar von oben nach unten: Herz ♥, Karo ♦, Pik ♠, Treff (Kreuz) ♣.

Aus dem Kontext verstehe ich hier daß „Farbe“ und „Gustierzeichen“ nicht den selben begriff sind.

Doch wenn man die [Regeln von Schnapsen](https://www.piatnik.com/uploads/media/default/0001/05/0935af7d1e0d7cfe5b0bbcfd0a01aaa71adc5d3d.pdf) liest (auch von Piatnik herausgegeben), steht:

> Es gibt vier Gustierzeichen bzw. „Farben“ (die 4 Symbole auf den Karten).

Ist „Gustierzeichen“ ein Synonym für „Farben“ oder nicht? Was soll „Gustierzeichen“ wirklich bedeuten? Ist daß dasselbe wie „Farbe“ ("suit" auf Englisch?) oder sind da die Buchstaben/Nummern in der Ecke von Spielkarten gemeint? (Sehe bild.)

[image: Gustierzeichen?]

...und daher haben „französische Karten“ keine „Gustierzeichen“?

[image: Französisches Blatt]

Oder sind beide Begriffe möglich? Meine Muttersprache ist Englisch. Wenn man „Gustierzeichen“ nachschaut findet man nur "approval mark" oder "taste mark" als übersetzung, und beim „Fach“ von Kartenspielen sind diese Übersetzungen sinnlos.

Comment: Wie kommst du zu dem Schluss, dass Farbzeichen und Gustierzeichen nicht dasselbe sind? Ich kann das nicht aus den zitierten Sätzen schließen.

Comment: @fluctuatingpsychosis Der Ursprung meines Zweifels kommt vom diesem Satz: Es gibt vier Gustierzeichen bzw. „Farben“. Das ist angeblich ein Äquivalenz, oder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Gustierzeichen* sind die auf die Ecken der Karten hinausgezogenen Mini-Symbole, die einem auf der Hand schnell zeigen, welche Karten man hält. Sehr alte (oder altertümliche) Spielkarten haben diese Gustierzeichen nicht.

In deinen zwei Bildbeispielen gibt es zwei verschiedene Gustierzeichen-Arten:

- das obere Bild trägt sowohl die Farbe (Herz, Pik, Kreuz, Karo) als auch den Kartenwert (7, 8, 9, 10, ...) . Davon gibt es natürlich viel mehr verschiedene als Farben
- das untere Beispiel hat nur bei den Assen Gustierzeichen.

Daneben kann man sich natürlich alle Kombinationen von Farbe und Wert vorstellen, die in Gustierzeichen vorkommen können. Üblich sind bei modernen deutschen Kartenspielen Gustierzeichen, die sowohl Farbe als auch Wert zeigen (wie in deinem ersten Beispiel).

Woher der Begriff kommt, darauf gibt der Grimm Auskunft:

> **GUSTIEREN**, vb.,
> kosten, an etwas geschmack finden, s. Staub-Tobler 2, 493; ausdruck beim hazard-kartenspiel, bedeutet: die karten mit der rückseite gegeneinander legen und langsam abziehen, so dasz eine zahl nach der anderen zum vorschein kommt und erst schlieszlich die ganze karte erkennbar ist Hügel Wien. 74: ihr langsames forschendes aufnehmen der karten (gustieren), indes ungeübte spieler ungeduldig und rasch zugreifen Grillparzer 12, 191 Sauer.

Comment: Dann fragt man sich nur noch, ob die *Abwesenheit* solcher Gustierzeichen irgendeinen Vorteil haben kann; schließlich deutet der zitierte Text an, dass diese für das Spiel entweder wichtig oder zumindest ein Qualitätsmerkmal für die Karten zu sein scheint.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Wie tofro im ersten Satz seiner Antwort richtig anmerkt, kommen Gustierzeichen bei alten Karten nicht vor. Sie sind eine neuere Entwicklung, eben weil sie einen Vorteil haben. Die Abwesenheit von Gustierzeichen ist somit keine absichtsvolle Veränderung von Karten mit Gustierzeichen, sondern eine ältere Form der Spielkarten. Weswegen die Frage danach, ob das Weglassen der Gustierzeichen einen Vorteil hätte, unsinnig ist, da sie nicht Weggelassen wurden, sondern auf den älteren Karten nie da waren und im Gegenteil bei neueren Karten hinzugefügt wurden.

Comment: @fluctuatingpsychosis: Der OP zitiert in der Frage: "Für Preference werden eigene Karten verwendet, nämlich französische Karten **ohne** Gustierzeichen." Offenbar waren dem Hersteller des Spiels bzw. dem Autor der Anleitung zum Zeitpunkt der Produktion Gustierzeichen also durchaus bekannt, man entschied sich aber bewusst dagegen, sie auf die Karten aufzudrucken. Im Klartext: Entgegen anderen zu jener Zeit bereits erhältlichen Karten wurden die Gustierzeichen für das genannte Spiel also in der Tat **absichtlich weggelassen**, was mE schon das Nachdenken über mögliche Vorteile berechtigt.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Préférence wird mit einer älteren Form der Spielkarten gespielt. Deshalb werden diese von den Herstellern unverändert reproduziert. Nur weil es heute noch Leute gibt, die mit dem Degen fechten, und nur weil diese Degen heute noch hergestellt werden, kann man deswegen nicht daraus schließen, dass Degen Vorteile gegenüber Schusswaffen haben müssten. Die Erklärung "ohne Gustierzeichen" stammt aus einer Spielanleitung, die sich an Spieler richtet, die Gustierzeichen gewohnt sind, und liefert eine Erklärung aus deren Perspektive.

Comment: @fluctuatingpsychosis: "Préférence wird mit einer älteren Form der Spielkarten gespielt." - warum? "Deshalb werden diese von den Herstellern unverändert reproduziert." - warum? Beides wird einen Grund haben - vermutlich einen Vorteil, der dafür spricht, auch für neue Reproduktionen genau diese ältere Form der Spielkarten nachzubilden und nicht mit dem heutigen Wissen über Gustierzeichen ebensolche hinzuzufügen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Jetzt wird's lächerlich. Warum gehen Menschen heute noch wandern, obwohl sie Auto fahren könnten? Warum werden überhaupt irgendwo traditionelle Formen verwendet? Nein, nicht weil das notwendigerweise immer einen Vorteil hat, sondern allein, weil es Spaß machen kann, ein Spiel in der traditionellen Form mit den traditionellen Karten zu spielen.

Comment: @fluctuatingpsychosis: Schon in meinem allerersten Kommentar erwähnte ich, dass das Weglassen des Gustierzeichens "ein Qualitätsmerkmal für die Karten" darstellen könnte. Deiner Einschätzung nach geht es dabei also rein um die Nostalgie; das Spiel würde mit Gustierzeichen genauso funktionieren. Das wird durch die zitierte Aussage nicht unbedingt nahegelegt, ist aber auch nicht ausgeschlossen. Antworte so was doch gleich :)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Was du zu ignorieren scheinst, ist dass gerade Kartenspiele einer extremen regionalen *Tradition* unterliegen (die Alemannen spielen Jass, die Österreicher Watten, die Norddeutschen Skat, die Schwaben Binokel, die Bayern Doppelkopf, die Franzosen Rommé und die Briten Bridge - alle mit bis heute ganz unterschiedlichen Karten)

Comment: @tofro: Vielleicht von besonders traditionalistisch eingestellten Kartenspielclubs abgesehen werden all diese Spiele (und weitere) heutzutage mit denselben Karten gespielt - hier in Süddeutschland zumeist mit dem französischen Blatt, in anderen Regionen mag das anders sein. Davon abgesehen ist die Frage, ob Karten nun ein bestimmtes Benutzbarkeitsmerkmal aufweisen, normalerweise orthogonal dazu, welche Art von Karten verwendet wird.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ich hab' noch nie Binokel oder Schafskopf mit "denselben" Karten wie Rommé gespielt gesehen. Tut mir leid, aber das ist ganz einfach nicht wahr.

Comment: @tofro: Ich verstehe nicht, was z.B. bei Binokel dagegen sprechen soll. Einfach das Mapping zum französischen Blatt (wie unter anderem [im Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binokel#Karten) aufgeführt) anwenden und los geht's.